# is this fungus?

Tags: water, waterproofing, humidity, cement, fungus

There is water constantly flowing from the balcony of my neighbor on the asphalt and in turn splashing on the wall.

There's a huge permanent stain there and looks like something fishy:

[image: a wall with what appears to be mottled grey and green discoloration, and pock-marks, near its bottom]

Is this fungus?

Comment: The discoloration, I'm guessing is the cement being tainted by the water. But I'm personally concerned by the greenish spots on the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Looks more like algae - wet location, sunshine, photosynthesis, chlorophyll.

Comment: So does that mean I can leave it in place?